# How can I keep the state saved when I coming to same route component from another in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a claims dropdown and function called on change of dropdown value is like this:

```
changeDdVal(v) {
  this.$store.dispatch('getUserRoles').then(userRoles => {
    if (userRoles.admin) {
      this.selectedYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      switch (v) {
        case 1:
          this.dropValue = "salesClaimCount";
          this.headerDropdownClaim = "sales";
          this.tableHeadData = this.salesTableHeadData;
          this.api.filterData = "getSalesClaimFilterDataForApprover";
          this.$router.push({name: this.routeName, params: {approverClaimType: this.claimTableData.claimStatus, dropType: this.headerDropdownClaim, userRole: this.role}})
            .catch(() => {});
          this.yearChange(this.selectedYear);
          break;
        case 2:
          this.dropValue = "staffingClaimCount";
          this.headerDropdownClaim = "staffing";
          this.tableHeadData = this.placementTableHeadData;
          this.api.filterData = "getStaffingClaimFilterDataForApprover";
          this.$router.push({name: this.routeName, params: {approverClaimType: this.claimTableData.claimStatus, dropType: this.headerDropdownClaim, userRole: this.role}})
            .catch(() => {});
          this.yearChange(this.selectedYear);
          break;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

And this yearChange function is taking care of calling api with the selected year and display data accordingly. I am calling this changeDdVal function on created state. When the data is displayed and if I click on any data, I am routing to detail view of that particular record.

Now the problem is when I change the year to any other from current year and click on that particular year data and come back to dashboard using "$router.go(-1)", my states resets i.e the year changes to current again but I want to remain in the selected year.
I know this is happening because of the "this.selectedYear = new Date().getFullYear();" and I can use vuex to store the state instead of this.
But in my case I want to reset the state on drop change and save the state if I come from the detail view of that record of selected year.

For example, by default the year is 2022 and I change it to 2021 the data is shown of 2021 and I click on any record of 2021 and use $router.go(-1) on that I should be in 2021. And if I have selected 2021 year and change the drop from sales to placement the year should reset to 2022.

this is my year change function

```
       yearChange() {
            this.axiosCancelToken.cancel("cancel requested")
            this.changeYear = false;
            this.firstLoad = true;
            this.sortBy =  "claimId";
            this.sortType = "descending";
            this.handlePagination(this.paginationOptions);
            this.mavePaginationList(false);
            this.fetchData();
            var dataApi = new FormData();
            dataApi.append("year", this.selectedYear);
            api
                .post(this.api.filterData, {data: dataApi})
                .then((res) => {
                    //resposne
           })
        },
```

Comment: Use the state management library, `vuex` or an alternative would be to use `keep-alive` component.

Comment: I can not use vuex here as I mentioned I need to reset state to initial on call of changeDdval function and not to reset on coming from detail view route. So using vuex with also keep the state saved for drop change that i don't want. And keep-alive is also not possible because the data is dynamic and it need to be refreshed. @NehaSoni

Comment: Vuex, agree. But I didn't get why keep-alive cannot be used, keep-alive will preserve the state when you come back from the route but it will be refreshed when you want to set any other data.

Comment: In my data there are some values for example the current state of claim i.e submitted, verified etc which can be changed from detail view and when I come back to dashboard after changing the state that record should have updated states. Similarly there is amount fields and some other fields which can be edited. All the data come from backend after change so the updated data should come from backend that's why keep-alive can't be used @NehaSoni

Comment: got it. Only some data should persist when coming back like the selected year and others can reset. Is this your case?

Comment: I need to do same thing with 2-3 other values also like pagination number and sorttype and sortBy. I thought of using url params and get it from url in created state but with this url will become too big @NehaSoni

Comment: I think Vuex can work. You can use `Vuex` for only params that need to persist. And if the params need to be saved and editable also, `vuex mapfields` can be helpful. Let me know if I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get you with this solution. What I exactly I need to do? should I do like this, If I can make a state in vuex like this "year: new Date().getFullYear()" and in the dashboard function use it as this.selectedYear = this.$store.state.year. And where ever the value of year changing pass it as "this.$store.state.year = value"? @NehaSoni

Comment: Yes, sort of but instead of using this.$store.state to get and mutate the selected year, I will recommend to use mapFields, here it is- https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-map-fields

Comment: But will this logic let me reset the state on drop change. I think it will also store the year selected to the dropdown change but I want to reset there @NehaSoni

Answer (score 0):

According to your question-

1. You need to keep some values saved when changing the route and some values to refresh as per API requests. (**keep-alive** won't do much in that use case.)
2. the values which need to persist are either a form variable (select dropdown) or some manual variable (pagination number).

As you said you can't use **Vuex** because of some problems, My guess, is that Vuex and **vuex-map-fields** together should ease the process of your problem.

**[vuex-map-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-map-fields) is a good way to enable two-way data binding for fields saved in a Vuex store.**

If I take your question as an example-
Suppose at your `Home.vue` you change the dropdown value, and on its changes, an API request gets fired and brings some data which you display on your component, and you can select any data which will lead to a new route, let's say `About.vue` and when you come back to `Home.vue` the year you selected should persist.

So, you can do this by like this-

1. Install the `vuex-map-fields` and configure it properly.
2. Create a property in your Vuex state of name, "`selectedYear`", like this-

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
// Import the `getField` getter and the `updateField`
// mutation function from the `vuex-map-fields` module.
import { getField, updateField } from "vuex-map-fields";

Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    selectedYear: null
  },
  getters: {
    // Add the `getField` getter to the
    // `getters` of your Vuex store instance.
    getField
  },
  mutations: {
    // Add the `updateField` mutation to the
    // `mutations` of your Vuex store instance.
    updateField
  }
});
```

3. In your Vue template, use this Vuex state property to get and mutate the `selectedYear`.

```
<select v-model="selectedYear" @change="callAPI()">
    <option>2020</option>
    <option>2021</option>
    <option>2022</option>
</select>
```

```
import { mapFields } from "vuex-map-fields";

export default {
  name: "Home",

  computed: {
    // The `mapFields` function takes an array of
    // field names and generates corresponding
    // computed properties with getter and setter
    // functions for accessing the Vuex store.
    ...mapFields(["selectedYear"]),
  },
}
```

And when you want to reset the dropdown state, simply do this-

```
this.selectedYear = null;
```

It will update in the Vuex state as well.

In that way, you should notice that when you switch the route, the selected box state will persist because this is bonded with the store.
In the same fashion, you can keep the state of pagination, and another variable you want.
The benefit of using `vuex-map-field` is that you don't need to write getter and setter functions manually to contact the state.

**Note-** If you want to persist your Vue state between page reloads also, then use [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) with Vuex.

As your code depends on multiple concepts, I cannot provide the snippet here, but I created a fiddle and try to reproduce the problem, you can look at it, and modify it according to your case and make sure things work.

In the fiddle, I used the same problem mentioned in your question (but the data and API request is dummy), and you should see when you change the routes (from `Home.vue` to `About.vue`), the year would persist but when reload the page it won't because I didn't use `vuex-persistedstate`.

Here it is- https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-forked-mdvdhd?file=/src/views/Home.vue:935-1181

Comment: This is also doing the same thing. Actually I have these dropdowns defined in same component only. So with your solution I am able to store the state when coming back to dashboard component i.e if i change year to 2021 and goto detail view of some record from there and come back using back button I am in 2021 only.
But now if I  want to reset the the year to 2022 on switch case i.e dropdown change that won't be possible. This is the real problem.

Comment: I have added the yearchange function also in question

Comment: If I get you right, why can't you reset the year to 2022, like- `this.selectedYear = 2022`.

Comment: apart from the question, you can mutate anything using `vuex-map-fields` either set or get. I don't get your issue that why you can't reset or something. If you have two dropdowns and both need to sync, both can be used with vuex-map-fields. It would be better if you can reproduce your problem in the fiddle I mentioned above.

Comment: This is what I need. please ignore my code writing. Here I am doing year change and showing the data according to year. when I am routing back to current page I am still in that year that's fine. But I want to change the year to 2022 on each claim dropdown change and want to remain on the selected year when coming from detail view.
 [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-forked-tenc7g?file=/src/views/Home.vue)